# Ad hoc Mongoid models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, runtime, mongoid, field

I'd like to create a Mongoid model that has run-time ad-hoc fields based on some arbitrary structure.

Using dynamic fields won't cut it, since I'll be needing to use validations, custom types and embedding in the model.

Defining new fields and validations in a `after_initialize` block in the model by `class_eval`ing does work. However, the fields and validations accumulate in the model due to `class_eval`.

I have a hunch that you could make it work, if fields were defined at the instance level rather than the class level.

Love to get some pointers regarding this problem.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, because the way ActiveModel validations work, you won't be able to accomplish this.
What you can do, however, is define ad-hoc subclasses of your base class, and define the validation logic there. The whole thing seems quite hacky anyway. Would you like to describe the domain of the problem?

Comment: I'm making a model which will allow the users to add or edit fields for it. These fields also have custom validations, relations etc. So they're not really the default datatypes that Mongoid offers.

Comment: Ok. I think that the cleanest way would be to keep track of validations your self, e.g. class and options, for instance "PresenceValidator", "{allow_nil: true}", and then have in your before_save callback code, which will go over all those collected validations (which should be persisted in the db, btw), and instantiate the validator and call it on the instance.

Comment: Ok, they'll take care of the validations. That is kind of what I'm doing right now. In addition, I'm making my own accessors for reading and writing to the database. Lots of repeated code, but it works.